# Can Files.createFile() have asynchronous behaviour?

Tags: java, file, asynchronous, io, synchronous

I am getting a really strange behavior on a test server using Files.createFile().

With code looking like that :

```
Files.createFile(myPath);
... code adding that file to a zip file ...
```

The file created at myPath is SOMETIMES not included in the zip content, most often it is not included, no Exception thrown. I could never reproduce the issue outside of the test server which runs CentOS release 6.6 (Final) and has an ext4 file system. Performing a Files.exists(myPath) after createFile always returns true.

I tried writing a few characters to the file to check if it makes a difference, but it does not.

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(testLog.toFile(), "Test content");
```

If I add a short sleep in-between, the file is then included in the zip consistently.

Consistently working :

```
Files.createFile(myPath);
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //interrupted
}
... code adding that file to a zip file ...
```

My view on this is that there is some strange asynchronous behavior going on in the file system as a Thread.sleep() should never make any difference in this code.

Does anyone have a definite explanation on how that sleep can make a difference ?

EDIT : My problem here is really not about the zipping method but about the createFile method behaving asynchronously while it should not.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You only create a file but do not put contents in it?

Comment: It may be helpful to show the code that puts it in the zip file. The problem might be there.

Comment: Actually I tried with two different libraries and fundamentally it would not explain the Thread.sleep impact. I used zip4J and standard java zip library.

Comment: What OS are you using? If you're not doing enough disk I/O to force a write, the actual file creation on disk may be delayed. I also don't see any guarantee in the documentation that this call is synchronous. In fact, it says "In most cases, the methods defined here will delegate to the associated file system provider to perform the file operations." So you're really at the mercy of whatever the designated file system provider wants to do.

Comment: That means that I cannot trust the FileSystem to have created a file after `Files.createFile(myPath);`. That would imply that you cannot reliably use a file system in java to manipulate data. I would expect every java developer to complain about that if that was the case, no ? A file system with no guarantees that you can access a file after a successful call to create it would be worthless to me.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use the zip filesystem provider?

```
final Path zipPath = Paths.get("pathToZipFileHere");
final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipPath.toUri());

final Path fileInZip;

// Open the zip as a filesystem
try (
    final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri,
        Collections.emptyMap());
) {
    fileInZip = fs.getPath("path/in/zip");
    // work with fileInZip
}
```

Comment: The method to zip is irrelevant to me. The question is why does a synchronous IO call behave asynchronously? How can I trust simple file IO experiencing this kind of behavior ?

Comment: I mean that while using this method might fix the initial problem, it does not explain it. I'm really after an explanation in this case. But indeed this method is interesting.